# Extract non sequential pages to one document in adobe acrobat pro DC using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I want to extract pages in adobe acrobat pro DC **using Javascrip**t.
But I want to extract **non sequential** pages into **one** document.

```
var thisDocPath = this.path.replace(thisDocName, "") //folder path (without file name)
var thisDocName = this.documentFileName //file name with extension
    
  this.extractPages({
    nStart: [2,6,1],
    cPath: thisDocPath + thisDocName.replace(/.pdf/g, "") + "test " + ".pdf"
  });
```

It only extracts a single page.

I have even tried for loop with this. But it extracts 3 separate documents.

Any workaround?

Currently I am thinking of opening a new document and inserting pages with a for loop. Can you suggest a better solution?